# what *p1 ^= *p2; does in c

Tags: c, compound-assignment

In C what does this statement do?

```
*p1 ^= *p2;
```

`p1` and `p2` are char pointers pointing to two different address of a char array. I know about `^` operator is XOR.

Comment: If you know about `^` then you know what that statement does.

Comment: XORing the data pointed by the two and storing the result in the address pointed by `p1`.

Comment: ^ is the exclusive or operator. a ^= b is an abbreviation of a = a ^ b.

Comment: The `^=` is a single operator.  You may be more familiar with its analog, `+=`.  The effect of the statement follows directly from the behavior of the operators involved in it, `*` and `^=`, which you certainly are capable of looking up for yourself if you need to do.

Comment: It's the same as `*p1 = *p1 ^ *p2`.  "The value of p1 is set to the value of p1 xored with the value of p2."  In the case where the char pointers are both pointing to 2, it changes the value of p1 to 0.  (Because a ^ a = 0)

Answer (score 2):

It should probably be easier to understand if you see it this way instead:

```
char c1 = *p1;
char c2 = *p2;

c1 = c1 ^ c2;

*p1 = c1;
```

That's basically what the code you show is doing.

This of course relies on you knowing how [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) actually works, and know about pointer dereferencing too.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
*p1 ^= *p2;
```

is the compound assignment operator with the bitwise exclusive OR operator,

It is a substitution for this expression statement

```
*p1 = *p1 ^ *p2;
```

Answer (score 0):

When apply `^` on `char` variable, just regard it as `int`.

```
define VALUE 11
char c = VALUE;
int i = VALUE;
```

Cause you can think that the **value** of `c` or `i` are same in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise exclusive OR operator (^) compares each bit of its first operand to the corresponding bit of its second operand. If one bit is 0 and the other bit is 1, the corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding result bit is set to 0.
Both operands to the bitwise exclusive OR operator must be of integral types. The usual arithmetic conversions covered in Arithmetic Conversions are applied to the operands.